# Do we have any ways to make the common/shared library for bootloader and application for RTOS based system

Tags: iar

I am developing RTOS based application with libraries given by the vendor. Now same library i need in Bootloader also. My concern is why don't we use common library placement so the we can reduce the memory usage. Project are done using C language and RTOS. I am using Freescale 32 bit controller with IAR. In IAR any way we can do the library reuse by placing in common flash for bootloader and application?. Need input

Comment: A processor executes instructions.  In that regard, it doesn't care whether it is running a "bootloader" - the differentiation is made in that the bootloader is less frequently changed than the other part, and is used to perform the changing of that part.  If you know where the library physically resides, you should be able to reuse that portion.  At some point, customizing and finely controlling what is loaded to cpu caches (and the how/when) becomes the act of developing an rtos.

Comment: Why don’t ‘we’? It’s up to you to tell the linker where things are located so you should be able to do what you propose. Usually the bootloader has the bare minimum code in a single chip micro application, so the proposed issue doesn’t exist. The main app downloads the new code, sets a known memory location and reboots where the bootloader takes control, finds the flag then validates the downloaded app then moves it into flash.

Comment: Why would you even need FreeRTOS in the bootloader, or want to share e.g. single FreeRTOS library between bootloader and application? If FreeRTOS has a bug and you update it, you can't because bootloader is using the part you need to update.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but not a simple project to tackle at all. Unless you're so short of code space that you have no other option (after turning on all the optimizations your compiler has to offer, etc) I wouldn't bother even trying.

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs

Answer (score 0):

In an RTOS application tasks/processes can only share reentrant functions.

Reentrant functions are written in a way that they work only on arguments received from the calling function.

Example: strtok() which is a libc function is not reentrant.

Answer:

IAR Compiler/linker will do anything to save code space in your application and will share all reentrant functions.

If the boot loader is a stand alone executable there's no way to share code with your application simply because it is built as a separate project.

Usually boot loaders do very little and don't use many libc functions. They just verify the signature of the binary image and then copy it to RAM for execution or jump to flash for XIP execution in place.

Comment: I am using same libraries and functions in both Bootloader and Application. Can we make load common library in flash and use from both application?

Comment: @Nitesh Can it be done?  Yes.  Is it easy?  No.  All of the development tools I have used are great for creating self contained applications (like a bootloader or runtime application) because they combine the application code and libraries to create the final application.  To do what you are suggesting, you would have a third "application" which is the common code.  The bootloader and runtime code would need to access the common code through an interface that "knows" the location of the common code.  Again, not easy, but certainly doable.

Comment: Thanks for input